# How can I reduce the time (TTFB) of the post request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a web site.I use both MVC 5 and Web api.
The TTFB is too long (6~10 s) for the web api request, but the mvc view's ttfb(1~2 s) is acceptable.
And when I post many request to the same api, only the first request has the problem.

*this is my code in Login method*

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Login(LoginInfo loginInfo)
    {
        string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { status = "example" });

        //check the whether user is already login
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
            && loginInfo.UserName == (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["user"])
        {
            result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { status = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["role"] });
            return new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StringContent(result, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") };
        }

        Student student = studentRepo.GetById(loginInfo.UserName);
        if (student == null)
        {
            result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { status = "usr" });
        }
        else
        {
            string password;
            string salt = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["salt"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(salt))
            {
                //the login page has expired 
                result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { status = "expire" });
            }
            else
            {
                password = student.Password + salt;
                password = MD5Helper.GetMd5(password);
                if (password == loginInfo.Password)
                {
                    //login success!
                    HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove("salt");
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginInfo.UserName, false);
                    HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("user", student.StuNo);
                    HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("role", student.Role);
                    result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { status = student.Role });
                }
                else
                {
                    result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { status = "deny" });
                }
            }
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StringContent(result, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I deployed my app to another server and the TTFB became shorter. And the problem about that session was deleted frequently is also fixed.